# Difference between 来ることはない and 来ない？

Tags: word-choice, nuances

I am not sure if there is a difference between them or not them. Basically I would like to know what the (verb)ことはない form means.

Comment: Basically it adds *it won't happen that ....* or *it is impossible that ...*.

Answer (score 7):

> 1. 彼は来ない。
> 2. 彼が来ることはない。

The first sentence simply denies he will come.

The second sentence specifically denies the possibility of him coming in implicit contrast with other possibilities. Many other things might happen but his coming will not be one of them.

Comment: "never came" would need to be 来たことはない (past tense).  彼が来ることはない means either "he will never come" (i.e. "there is no possibility that he will come"), or possibly "He doesn't ever come" ("he has never come to this recurring thing up to now").  (or both)

Comment: I removed several comments. Please let's all remember to Be Nice. We're all here to learn and/or teach and I'm really happy that in the vast majority of cases it's happening in a respectful and supportive way. Let's keep it that way.

Comment: For the record, someone did downvote this answer.

Comment: @aguijonazo I saw that too. And that without doubt is an unfair downvote. I think it could be from a certain someone despite them claiming otherwise. But it's a general policy that votes are not discussed publicly. Even moderators have no way to know who cast isolated votes.

Comment: The total number of up- and downvotes can be seen by [all users with 1000 reputation](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user). Anonymous voting is part of the Stack Exchange model, for upvotes and downvotes alike, but targeted downvoting is prohibited (and there are measures against it). Although individual downvotes might feel discouraging, unfair downvotes are quite rare and as a question or answer gathers more votes, they just end up adding some small noise to the signal.